# How to set zeros and ones in dataframe based on value in another columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to set column values to zero's and one's based on another coulmn in a data-frame.

I tried multiple ways(pivot with null values and get_dummies.etc),however could not achieve desired results looks like values are getting overwritten.

Could someone please help.

df

```
item_code       sale_val    Trans_id
11              10.00       1111
11              10.00       2222
12              2.00        1111
13              1.05        2222
13              1.05        1111
14              3.00        1111
12              2.00        3333
14              3.00        3333
14              3.00        4444
```

df1-
group by trans id shows below format

```
item_code       sale_val    Trans_id
11              10.0        111
13              10.0        222
12              2.0         111
12              2.0         333
13              1.05        111
11              1.05        222
14              3.0         111
14              3.0         333
```

pd.get_dummies was run against df1 and sets value "1"  first item id in a  given trans_id. 
Ex:Trans_id 111,item_code 11 was set to 1 and 12 to 14 item codes were set 0 or probably would have overwritten while setting values for other trans_ids.

```
Trans_id/index  11  12  13  14 
111             1   0   0   0   
222             1   0   0   0   
333             1   0   0   0
```

```
#exclude transid count < 1 
df1=(df.groupby("Trans_id").filter(lambda x:len(x)>1)
#generate ones & zeros
df2=pd.get_dummies(df1,columns=['item_code'])
```

Expected format

```
Trans_id/index  11  12  13  14 
111             1   1   1   1   
222             1   0   1   0   
333             0   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then get `max` per first level:

```
#faster solution in large df
df1 = df[df["Trans_id"].duplicated(keep=False)]

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('Trans_id')['item_code']).max(level=0)
print (df2)
          11  12  13  14
Trans_id                
1111       1   1   1   1
2222       1   0   1   0
3333       0   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.pivot(columns='item_code',index='Trans_id').fillna(0)>0).astype(int)

          sale_val         
item_code       11 12 13 14
Trans_id                   
111              1  1  1  1
222              1  0  1  0
333              0  1  0  1
```